# trim of extra character from the dropdown box

Tags: java

I have one text box in the User Interface where in user is asked to key in some input , which in turn i am saving in database , which finally i have to show in the dynamically populated dropdown list . since the user can type in any ways in the text box as in

1. XXXXXX
2. XXXXXX
   or

   1.XXXXXX ,2. XXXXXXX

or 
  XXXXXXXXX,  XXXXXXXX

but i want to just get the value of these so that i can show just text value in my dropdown .

Can someone help in parsing this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the formats you are supposed to parse. If they are exactly the above three, then:

1. get rid of all digits with `string.replaceAll("\\d\\.", "")`
2. split on comma or split on new line (`str.split("\\n")`
3. `str.trim()` everything, just in case

Comment: I think that one parameter is missing when you call `replaceAll` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trim() method to get the value and remove the white spaces.